# How to style each React route independently?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and React Router and I am facing some trouble regarding the styling of the routes. So basically I have 2 routes: the main page and the admin page. All I want to do is to style the body so that in the admin page everything is centered. The problem is that each time i style the body, all the styling goes to the main page too. So how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you centering the whole document body?

Comment: That's what I want to do. But only for the admin route, not all routes.

Comment: Can you show your sample code?

Comment: Why don't you do that for the Container DIV that wraps the JSX of the component that represents the admin route? I mean instead of `body {}`

Comment: any code for the admin route would be helpful to describe a proper solution

Comment: @SultanH. for some reason this didn't work before but not it seems to haha. Thank you, but anyways, if this wasn't a fix, how could that still be achieved? I mean styling the body differently for each route.

Comment: I don't think that would be achievable unless you use the DOM<JS> way, because, the second route will always dominate the style of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You might me applying styling to you `app.js` file where `BrowserRouter` is implemented. Here is what you can do. Create your `Home/Main` page as:

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return <div style={{textAlign: "center" }}>Home</div>
}

export default Home;
```

Create your `Admin` page as:

```
import React from "react";

const Admin = () => {
  return <div>Admin</div>
}

export default Admin;
```

And finally, Create your `app.js` file as:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Admin from "./Admin";
import Admin from "./Home";

const App = () => {
  return <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
}

export default App;
```

In this way, your only your `Home` page content is aligned centered. Hope this will help you.